# Array overflow c++ (at arr[0])?

Tags: c++, arrays

Ok so last night I taught my sister some basic code how to read input, put it in array and print it to the screen. Here is the code :

```
int main() {
    int N;  // size of array

    cin >> N;
    int arr[N];

    for(int i = 1; i<= N; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the result :

```
input :
4
2 3 4 1

output :
8
2
3
4
```

I don't have any clues why this can happen, I tried to check the code but it seems simple and already correct for me.

Comment: array-indices start with 0, not 1.

Comment: Variable length arrays are not standard C++ and not portable. I'd suggest using a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Stay away from the variable length arrays.  Use `std::vector` instead.  Using `std::vector` not only makes your program standard C++, you have the chance to check your own errors [like this](http://ideone.com/2wr9zi) using `at()`.

Comment: Thanks, I realize the mistake now, how silly of me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you have to look after is that dasblinkenlight has already mentioned in his answer, *variable-length arrays are a language extension.*

Then you should think that arrays are zero index based. What does this means? Let's consider an array of size 4 that is denoted as `arr`. Then it's elements  can be accessed as `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, `arr[2]`, and `arr[3]`. So what happens when you run your first loop?

```
for(int i = 1; i<= N; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
}
```

You set the a value for `arr[1]`, `arr[2]` to `arr[N]`. But the `arr[N]` points to a place in memory that is not associated with the array, since the array's size is N and all arrays are zero based. The last element of the array lives in here `arr[n-1]`.

Unfortunately in C++ there isn't any check for the length of an array and you are allowed to do things like this. For instance, if you had tried this in C# or in Java then you would have got an Index Out Of Range Exception.

If you change your code to the following, then you will get the expected output:

```
for(int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
}

for(int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: `in C++ there isn't any check for the length of an array and you are allowed to do things like this. For instance, if you had tried this in C# or in Java then you would have got an Index Out Of Range Exception.` Plain arrays, sure. But if the OP wanted to protect against stuff like this during development, they could use `std::array` and index using `.at(i)`, which would throw exactly that kind of exception. Or, better, use a 'debug mode' version of `std::array` as in various compilers, which checks on `operator[]`, so you don't have to `s/\.at(\(\d*\))/[\1]/g` on release, as we usually should

Comment: I should clarify that everything I said above also applies to `std::vector`, which can be thought of as the dynamically sized equivalent of `std::array` and so, as Vlad and PaulM have noted, is probably more relevant here.

Answer (score 4):

First of all C++ does not support variable length arrays and if an array is declared as having N elements then the valid range of indices is `[0, N-1]`.

You could either dynamically allocate an array of the required size yourself or use standard container `std::vector<int>`.

Using `std::vector<int>` you could for example write

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    unsigned int n = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter number of elements: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> v( n );

    std::cout << "Enter " << n << " elements: ";

    for ( int &x : v ) std::cin >> x;

    std::cout << "\nThe array is ";

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter number of elements: 10
Enter 10 elements: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

The array is 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not valid C++, because variable-length arrays are a language extension.

With that part out of our way, consider what happens in your first loop's last step: you are accessing an element past the end of the array, which is undefined behavior.

Your second loop is correct, though, so all you need to do is correcting the header of the first loop to match the header of the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

An array of N elements has indexes from 0 to N-1 (so: N-1 - 0 + 1 = N elements, some maths.)

So fix this: `for(int i = 1; i<= N; i++)` with this : `for(int i = 1; i< N; i++)`

Comment: This assumes the OP doesn't want to `cin` to `arr[0]`, which context suggests is false.